# std::async uses same thread and my code does not achieve parallelism.

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future, promise

I am using C++11 on Mac OS Xcode 4.3.2
std::async uses same thread and my code does not achieve parallelism. In sample code below I want to create 10 new threads. In each thread I want to calculate square root of input variable and set the result in promise. in main function I want to display the results calculated from threads. I am calling std::async with policy launch::async, So I expect it to create a new thread(10 times).

```
    #include <mutex>
    #include <future>
    #include <thread>
    #include <vector>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    mutex iomutex;

    void foo(int i, promise<double> &&prms)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
        prms.set_value(sqrt(i));
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lg(iomutex);
            cout << endl << "thread index=> " << i << ", id=> "<< this_thread::get_id();
        }
    }

    int main() 
    {   
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lg(iomutex);
            cout << endl << "main thread id=>"<< this_thread::get_id();
        }
        vector<future<double>> futureVec;
        vector<promise<double>> prmsVec;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            promise<double> prms;
            future<double> ftr = prms.get_future();
            futureVec.push_back(move(ftr));
            prmsVec.push_back(move(prms));

            async(launch::async, foo, i, move(prmsVec[i]));
        }

        for (auto iter = futureVec.begin(); iter != futureVec.end(); ++iter) {
            cout << endl << iter->get();
        }

        cout << endl << "done";

        return 0;

    }
```

However if I use std::thread, then I can achieve parallelism.

```
    #include <mutex>
    #include <future>
    #include <thread>
    #include <vector>
    #include <cmath>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;
    mutex iomutex;

    void foo(int i, promise<double> &&prms)
    {
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
        prms.set_value(sqrt(i));
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lg(iomutex);
            cout << endl << "thread index=> " << i << ", id=> "<< this_thread::get_id();
        }
    }

    int main() 
    {   
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lg(iomutex);
            cout << endl << "main thread id=>"<< this_thread::get_id();
        }
        vector<future<double>> futureVec;
        vector<promise<double>> prmsVec;
        vector<thread> thrdVec;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            promise<double> prms;
            future<double> ftr = prms.get_future();
            futureVec.push_back(move(ftr));
            prmsVec.push_back(move(prms));

            thread th(foo, i, move(prmsVec[i]));
            thrdVec.push_back(move(th));
        }

        for (auto iter = futureVec.begin(); iter != futureVec.end(); ++iter) {
            cout << endl << iter->get();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            thrdVec[i].join();
        }
        cout << endl << "done";

        return 0;

    }
```

Comment: The implementation of the `thread` library on older gccs is not really functional. Try it on something non-ancient.

Comment: @pmr : I thought Clang was the default compiler in Xcode 4.2+?

Comment: @ildjarn You are right, of course. I mistook the 4.3.2 to mean a gcc version (XCode used gcc 4.something for a long time).

Answer (score 18):

```
            async(launch::async, foo, i, move(prmsVec[i]));
```

This line returns a `future` but because you do not assign it to anything the future's destructor runs at the end of the statement, which blocks and waits for the result by calling `std::future::wait()`

Why are you manually calling `std::async` with a promise, when it returns a future anyway?  The point of async is that you don't need to manually use a promise, that's done internally for you.

Rewrite your `foo()` to return `double` then call it with `async`

```
#include <mutex>
#include <future>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
mutex iomutex;

double foo(int i)
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(2));
    lock_guard<mutex> lg(iomutex);
    cout << "\nthread index=> " << i << ", id=> "<< this_thread::get_id();
    return sqrt(i);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "\nmain thread id=>" << this_thread::get_id();
    vector<future<double>> futureVec;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        futureVec.push_back(async(launch::async, foo, i));

    for (auto& fut : futureVec)
    {
        auto x = fut.get();
        lock_guard<mutex> lg(iomutex);
        cout << endl << x;
    }

    cout << "\ndone\n";
}
```

Comment: Once we are in the for loop, it's sequential code. No need of mutex here.

Comment: I wanted to make use of Promise and async together. Does that mean that if we use Promise with std::async then it cannot behave as async and always behave as sync call?

Comment: @Jagannath: no, on the first iteration you've waited for one future, there are nine threads that could still be running and writing to cout. On the second iteration there could still be eight threads writing to cout etc. (@sehe thanks for the code improvements)

Comment: @Vijay Kumar: no, it doesn't mean that, using `async` and `promise` is a bit weird and pointless, but can be done if you really want to. The problem in your code is not that you're using `promise`, the problem is that you ignore the return value of `async`. If you want to use `async` then you must assign the return value to something. If you call `async` and ignore the result it will be synchronous.  So don't do that.

Comment: I don't understand something. Why `push_back` and not `emplace_back`? Does it make a difference? Isn't `emplace_back` more natural since the product of `async` is moveable and not copyable.

Comment: @alfC, it makes absolutely no difference here. `emplace_back` allows you to construct the element from arbitrary arguments, but IMHO when inserting an object that is already the right type `push_back` is more natural (it's also less typing). Whether it's move-only or not is irrelevant, `push_back` works with rvalues of move-only types.